How commonly understood is the word UI?
Is it reasonable to expect English-speaking adults to understand the word UI to mean "user interface" in the context of the software they're using?

It is probably commonly understood by tech-savvy people.

Not all English-speaking adults are fluent enough to understand every abbreviation and subtlety, although they may be intelligent enough to understand clear prose, which avoids local idioms. Don't use casual phrases in manuals.

The Ngram for UI,TV,USB,CRT is interesting:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=UI%2CTV%2CUSB%2CCRT&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&case_insensitive=true&corpus=en&smoothing=3

How could anybody know this isn't Unemployment Insurance, or a Urinary-tract Infection, or Urinary Incontinence, or Under the Influence, or the University of Iowa or Indiana, or Unidad Internacional, or Unidentified Individual? Even if you tell them that it's a "User Interface", how in the world are they suppose to know what that means? Would an old farmer understand you? Even so, which xUI do you mean: A graphical one (GUI), or a haptic one (HUI), or a human one (HUI), or a text one (TUI), or a dip switch one (DUI), or any number of other "user" "interfaces"?

Misunderstandings about acronyms may be avoided by defining them on first use in any piece of prose. If this is not done, there is generally great scope for confusion or obscurity.
In some cases there may be a large enough body of people who may be expected to know an acronym without definition. For example, most of the world knows USA (United States of America).
If prose is intended for a specialist group that habitually uses an acronym, there may be no need to define it. The UK (United Kingdom) research community is accustomed to a PI being a Principal Investigator, although the term is not used widely outside that community.
Your question asks about a large body of people (the English speaking world). A quick look online for the meaning of UI brings up many definitions. For example see https://www.acronymfinder.com/UI.html
Although you focus on software, that may include users as well as writers (who might be expected to know the acronym). The term is therefore not widely, unambiguously or uniquely understood so it is not reasonable to use it without first-use definition.

Probably AI is more widely understood given its recent common and widespread usage on all sorts of media.

@user66974 I'm pretty sure that 'AI' is thoroughly misunderstood, being the current buzzword used by the media.

Yeah in general putting a quick definition in parentheses is always wise for acronyms and jargon. For instance as a coder if I say "This system accepts pure functions (A pure function is any function that alters no variables or environmental factors outside its return values)" then a new coder will be more likely to understand what I mean.
